# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Poker Stack Exchange](http://poker.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://poker.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Bully short stacks later on or try knock them out?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/bully-short-stacks-later-on-or-try-knock-them-out)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Order for revealing hands with multiple side pots in play](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4032/texas-holdem-order-of-reveal-with-multiple-side-pots)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Calculating equity of ranges](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4081/calculating-equity-of-ranges)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What are the odds of flopping a straight flush with 62s?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4022/what-are-the-odds-of-flopping-a-straight-flush-with-62s)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can there be more betting after an all-in covering a min raise amount?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/all-in-covering-a-min-raise)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why some people all-in in the VERY first hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/why-some-people-all-in-in-the-very-first-hand)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Should I have folded near the end of this tournament?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4025/should-i-have-folded-here-hero-is-cashcow5)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Counting outs? Any websites provide this?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4015/counting-outs-any-websites-provide-this)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Term for when all players go all-in and show hands](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/term-for-when-all-players-go-all-in-and-show-hands)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [mathematical profit](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/mathematical-profit)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 4)

---